# How do I debug Jquery Success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Javascript to get records from the database, everything works the way i want but i cannot show alerts in success handler. When i place a break point to sucess:function(data) it gets hit but this line is not being hit `$("#Alert").html(data).show()....` **Another** unusually thing i have noticed is that some time `$("#Alert").html(data).show()..` gets hit. Is there any way i can debug this?

```
        function MethodNAme() {
        ajReq.abort();
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/",
            data: ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                         getSomething();
            $("#Alert").html(data).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();   
            alert("working");

        }
    }
```

Comment: use console.log(), alert is not recommended

Comment: your code is incorrect remove `getSomething();` and use `.done` method, check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is not correct, you are placing a function `getSomething()` in middle of $.ajax(),

```
function MethodNAme() {
    ajReq.abort();
    ajReq = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
     //       getSomething(); <-- remove this
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Alert").html(data).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();   
            alert("working");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That should go inside success handler, that was my mistake. I,ve updated this in question.

Comment: well, what does that do..? can you post getSomething()'s code too..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log()` to print data in browser console. You can access console window by pressing `F12` key and then go to console tab.